# Python Telegram Bot Api shows error Message text is empty how to debug

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests, telegram-bot

i there i'am doing a medical chatbot project using telegram bot api and Apimedic Api when i

> /start

first bot reply(which asks for language selection) works fine after that it as to return to ask Gender after that Age and so on

```
def start(bot, update):
    reply_keyboard = [["English", "हिंदी"], ["मराठी", "বাংলা"]]
    lang_pick = "Please select your language.\nअपना भाषा चुनें।\nकृपया तुमची भाषा निवडा\nআপনার ভাষা নির্বাচন করুন"
    update.message.reply_text(lang_pick,
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(reply_keyboard, one_time_keyboard=True))

    return LANGUAGE

def language(bot, update, user_data):
    reply_keyboard = [['Male', 'Female'], ['Other']]
    user = update.message.from_user
    text = update.message.text
    user_data["lang"] = lang_map[text]
    welcome_text = "Hi {}! I will help you with your medical conditions.\nSend /cancel to stop talking to me.\n\nPlease select your Gender.".format(user.first_name)
    update.message.reply_text(translate_from_english(welcome_text, user_data["lang"]),
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(reply_keyboard, one_time_keyboard=True))

    return GENDER

def gender(bot, update, user_data):
    user = update.message.from_user
    text = update.message.text
    user_data["gender"] = text
    logger.info("Gender of %s: %s", user.first_name, update.message.text)
    reply = 'I see! Please tell me about your Age, so I can detect disease easily.'
    update.message.reply_text(translate_from_english(reply, user_data["lang"]), reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())

    return AGE
```

but instead it shows this error.

```
Starting..!
    2021-02-10 07:47:08,728 - __main__ - INFO - Waking Up Bot.
    2021-02-10 07:47:08,730 - __main__ - INFO - Bot is polling for sessions.
    2021-02-10 07:47:55,224 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - WARNING - A TelegramError was raised while processing the Update
    2021-02-10 07:47:55,225 - __main__ - WARNING - Update "{'update_id': 472297741,
    'message': {'message_id': 3, 'date': 1612923477, 'chat': {'id': 1680986729, 'typ
    e': 'private', 'first_name': 'Gopi'}, 'text': 'English', 'entities': [], 'captio
    n_entities': [], 'photo': [], 'new_chat_members': [], 'new_chat_photo': [], 'del
    ete_chat_photo': False, 'group_chat_created': False, 'supergroup_chat_created':
    False, 'channel_chat_created': False, 'from': {'id': 1680986729, 'first_name': '
    Gopi', 'is_bot': False, 'language_code': 'en'}}, '_effective_user': {'id': 16809
    86729, 'first_name': 'Gopi', 'is_bot': False, 'language_code': 'en'}, '_effectiv
    e_chat': {'id': 1680986729, 'type': 'private', 'first_name': 'Gopi'}, '_effectiv
    e_message': {'message_id': 3, 'date': 1612923477, 'chat': {'id': 1680986729, 'ty
    pe': 'private', 'first_name': 'Gopi'}, 'text': 'English', 'entities': [], 'capti
    on_entities': [], 'photo': [], 'new_chat_members': [], 'new_chat_photo': [], 'de
    lete_chat_photo': False, 'group_chat_created': False, 'supergroup_chat_created':
     False, 'channel_chat_created': False, 'from': {'id': 1680986729, 'first_name':
    'Gopi', 'is_bot': False, 'language_code': 'en'}}}" caused error "Message text is empty"
```

i'am using  **python-telegram-bot 11.0.0** which is suitable for my python code. here is that code sample

```
from telegram import (ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove)
from telegram.ext import (Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, RegexHandler,
                          ConversationHandler)
```

this is my handler the token is just example not actual

```
def main():
    # Create the EventHandler and pass it your bot's token.
    print('Starting..!')
    logger.info("Waking Up Bot.")
    updater = Updater("2483457814:AAHrlCx234_VskzWEJdWjTsdfuwejHyu5mI")

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # Add conversation handler with the states GENDER, PHOTO, LOCATION and BIO
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],

        states={
            LANGUAGE: [RegexHandler('^(English)$', language, pass_user_data=True)],

            GENDER: [RegexHandler('^(Male|Female|Other)$', gender, pass_user_data=True)],

            AGE: [RegexHandler('^[1-9][0-9]{0,1}$', age, pass_user_data=True),
                    CommandHandler('skip', skip_age, pass_user_data=True)],

            LOCATION: [MessageHandler(Filters.location, location, pass_user_data=True),
                       CommandHandler('skip', skip_location, pass_user_data=True)],

            BIO: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, bio, pass_user_data=True)]
        },

        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)]
    )

    dp.add_handler(conv_handler)

    # log all errors
    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    # Start the Bot
    logger.info("Bot is polling for sessions.")
    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()
```